# Ejecutar consulta en Access desde C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo el siguiente código en C# que uso para consultar información de una base de datos en Access:

```
public DataTable selcfecharegitro()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection cone = new OleDbConnection(cc.conaccess);
    string desde = Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtpdesde.Value.ToShortDateString());     
    string hasta = Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtphasta.Value.ToShortDateString());
    da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from Registro where Fecha_uso  between @desde and @hasta ", cone);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde", desde);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta", hasta);

    da.Fill(ds);

    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    return dt;
}
```

No me muestra errores, lo que pasa es que no me muestra los datos que le pido, solo muestra el nombre de las tablas pero no los datos que están en ellas.

¿Cómo puedo obtener los registros de la tabla?

Comment: En la base de datos de Access los campos de fecha están definidos como date o como string? Ya probaste a ejecutar la consulta directamente sobre la base de datos para ver si arroja resultados?

Answer (score 2):

En Access, utiliza el signo de # para marcar fechas literales, la idea es esta:

```
SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Fecha_Uso Between #@desde# And #@hasta#;
```

Para hacerlo funcionar:

```
string desde = "#"+ Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtpdesde.Value.ToShortDateString()) + "#";     
string hasta = "#" Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtphasta.Value.ToShortDateString()) + "#";
```

**Actualización**

Recibimos los valores:

```
string desde = Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtpdesde.Value.ToShortDateString());     
string hasta = Convert.ToString(new datosform().dtphasta.Value.ToShortDateString());
```

La query:

```
SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Fecha_Uso >= ? And Fecha_Uso <= ?;
```

Sus parámetros:

```
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", desde);
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", hasta);
```

Comment: Me muestra error de sintaxis

Comment: acabo de actualizar la respuesta, intenta :D

Comment: Muestra este error >> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: ejecuta esta query: SELECT * FROM Registro WHERE Fecha_Uso Between #01/01/2016# And #02/02/2016/#;

Comment: si, si mlo ejecuta, pero con los datatimepikers no...

Comment: podrías confirmar que tu computadora tiene el mismo formato de fechas que los registros del Sistema porfavor?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52602/discussion-between-use2105-and-fredyfx).

Comment: Hola,en Access los parámetros se indican con interrogaciones.?.cambia tu consulta a da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from Registro where Fecha_uso  between ? and ?", cone);

Comment: Ya comprove que todo tenga el mismo format pero no funciona

Comment: al chat :D así mantenemos el sitio limpio de debates :D

Comment: De todas formas, si el campo Fecha_Uso es de tipo DateTime en Access, no es necesario convertir a ToShortDateString().

Comment: no pero no me muestra nasa

Comment: respuesta actualizada, intenta :D

Comment: no hace falta el format   # / / # ??

Comment: Qué es eso de new datosform().dtpdesde y new datosform().dtphasta? Estás instanciando un formulario nuevo? Puedes explicarlo?

Comment: yo el query lo hago en una clase aparte del furmulario, los new datosform().dtpdesde  new datosform().dtphasta son los DateTimerPickers donde el usuario selecciona las fechas, esto esta en el formulario.

Comment: @use2105, según lo leído en http://stackoverflow.com/a/31160733/3613462 no hace falta poner el # porque son datos parametrizados :D te funcionó? Por cierto, luego debemos eliminar estos comentarios para mantener el sitio limpio. Saludos

Comment: No me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quería decir con mis comentarios se ve en el siguiente código.

```
public DataTable selcfecharegitro() {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection cone = new OleDbConnection(cc.conaccess);
    da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from Registro where Fecha_uso  between ? and ? ", cone);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desde", fecha_desde_en_datetime);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hasta", fecha_hasta_datetime);

    da.Fill(ds);

    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    return dt; }
```

Comment: Por que los signos de  interrogacion??

Comment: Porque Access usa esos marcadores de posición para establecer los parámetros.

Comment: Aun asi me sigue mostrando las tablas vacias.

Comment: Hola. Querrás decir que la consulta no te devuelve resultados. Qué valores tienen los parámetros de fecha desde y hasta? Tienes un juego de datos que lo satisfacen? Si quitas el filtro te devuelve datos la query?